# Make table containing videos scale/stack for mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, scale

I have a table made up of 1 row and 3 columns. Each column has an embedded iframe Youtube video in and below that, a very short title and description (all in the same same ONE row). How would i make these 3 videos stack on top of each other for mobile users with the text for each appearing underneath the right the video?

Comment: you can't, not without javascript or changing the markup

Comment: Don't use tables for that. Use a responsive grid http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/calculator/  Also you really should show the code that you have tried!

Comment: @mlegg Responsive grids did the job perfectly. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction!